# solr NOW/DAY and timezones

Tags: datetime, solr, timezone

I stumbled upon a timezone problem once again. I know solr stores dates in UTC timezone and I know that my user comes from - lets say New York, tz=EST = UTC-4h

Problem:
I want to display data for today for the user.

I do this by query

> date:[NOW/DAY TO NOW/DAY+1DAY]

. This will give me wrong results, as I want to query from the start of the day EST time, not UTC.

Q: Is there a way to still use NOW/DAY and adjust for the timezones or do we always need to query with UTC date strings?

Answer (score 0):

One way is, you know the time zone difference. You know how solr stores it. So when a request comes, you can add/substract the time difference, and that will remain constant.

This logic will work only for one time zone. To scale it, you can have a common mapping stuff, where you can get the user time zone, and then mapping that to the UTC timezone. It takes effort, but its one time activity.

Comment: In this case I would need to modify the query, which is the question point. NOW/DAY will always give me data from UTC midnight regardless what timezone magic I do in the app. The user will therefore not get today's data, but UTC today's data

Comment: When you dont want to deal with UTC, you are going to loose the power of "NOW" i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround you could try in java is

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATEFORMAT);
    String userTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("Pacific/Midway");;
    sdf.setTimeZone(dtZone.toTimeZone());
    String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());

    String dateRange = dateInString.replaceAll("NOW", currentTime);
```

I have used the joda date time here. You could use java Date or Calendar.

This would be converted to something like this

```
date:[2016-05-30T01:51:00.841Z/DAY TO 2016-05-30T01:51:00.841Z/DAY+1DAY]
```